# Maybe wrong in Nonspreading wave packets for the cubic Schrödinger equation with a bounded potential

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Picture below is from 406th page of 
[**Nonspreading wave packets for the cubic Schrödinger equation with a bounded potential**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(86)90096-0). The $V$ is $C^2$ and $0$ is a nondegenerate critical point of $V$. How to get the red box ? In fact, I think it is wrong. Since $z+hy$ can be large, the remainder, in Taylor, can't be omitted. There should be $|z+hy|^3...$

> [image]